# How to receive local contacts with emai addresses using the content resolver

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I am developing an Android app and want to receive my local contacts. To be exact I want to display all contacts which have an email address. My current approach looks like this

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Data;

private static final String[] CONTACT_PROJECTION = new String[] {
 Email.CONTACT_ID,
 Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
 Email.ADDRESS,
};

Cursor data = mResolver.query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
 CONTACT_PROJECTION,
 Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
 null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " ASC");
```

The problem using this query is, that the result contains rows that doesn't match a contact in my local address book. Probably I used those email addresses before but didn't saved it to my address book.

I have already tried another approach where I made a query on `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` with `Contacts._ID`. This id is used as a foreign key to match the contacts in a second query against their emails. The solution was a nested cursor and the runtime was really slow. For a hundred contacts the query took more than two seconds to match. This is a reason for using the async `CursorLoader` but I want to avoid it if possible.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

**#Edit 1:**

Unfortunately both solutions don't archive the desired improvement.

For example, when I write a new email to a previous unknown address with my gmail app afterwards the address shows up in both querys with an contact id but not in my normal address book. This kind of "contacts" flood my query.

Could it be related to the value of ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE?

**#Edit 2:**

I found an interesting flag `Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1"`. It seems to filter the unwanted addresses.
Has somebody any experience with it? I don't want to filter to much.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I am using in my app:

```
public void readContacts(){
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                // get the phone number
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                       new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                      String phone = pCur.getString(
                             pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                      System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                }
                pCur.close();


                // get email and type

               Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                    // This would allow you get several email addresses
                        // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                    String email = emailCur.getString(
                                  emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                                  emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                    System.out.println("Email " + email + " Email Type : " + emailType);
                }
                emailCur.close();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have attached one of the functions used in my project. Point of intrest would be selection and selection args.

Snippet

```
selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " != ?";
selectionArgs = new String[]{""};
```

This says selection is based on email data and it should not be null.

Similarly you can add any of the selection params as per your need.

Entire Function

```
 public Cursor getInitCursorLoader() {
    String[] PROJECTION = null;
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[0];
    String order = null;
    Uri contentURI = null;
    switch (mFriendType) {
        case EMAIL:
            PROJECTION = new String[]{
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TIMES_CONTACTED,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA};
            selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " != ?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{""};
            contentURI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
            order = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TIMES_CONTACTED + " DESC";
            break;
        case SMS:
            PROJECTION = new String[]{
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TIMES_CONTACTED,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE};
            selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = ?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)};
            contentURI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
            order = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TIMES_CONTACTED + " DESC";
            break;
    }
    return mContext.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, order);
}
```